# Cannot Get Files From FTP using ANT

Tags: ant, ftp

I am trying to get files from FTP, it always says no files retrieved, 
here goes my code

```
<target name="ftp">

        <ftp action="get"
                     server="${myftpserver}"
                     userid="${username}"
                     password="${password}"
                     remotedir="a"
                     binary="no"
                     verbose="yes"
                     passive="yes">
                     <fileset dir="abc" includes="CatalogReferenceAttribute.java"/>
               </ftp>
        </target>
```

Here i am trying to retrieve a .java file from FTP folder

> a

to my local folder

> abc

below is my ouput
[image]

Where i was wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you put the dependency libraries into ANT's lib directory?
common-net.jar may not be enough... check this page:
http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies

Comment: Happy to see that. You can always find clues in the output when it was saying "could not load something" -- just check if there is such a thing or not.